# tf.decode_csv() error: "Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a csv file `blah.txt` that looks like:

```
1,2
3,4
```

I can read the csv as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
csv_train= tf.read_file('blah.txt')
csv_train.eval()
```

Which outputs:

```
Out[5]: '1,2\n3,4'
```

I'm trying to decode the csv as follows:

```
col1,col2 = tf.decode_csv(csv_train,
                          record_defaults=[tf.constant([],dtype=tf.int32),
                                           tf.constant([],dtype=tf.int32)])
```

Now when I run `col1.eval()` I get the error:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1102] 0x7ff203f17240 Compute status: Invalid argument: Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside
     [[Node: DecodeCSV_6 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], field_delim=",", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReadFile, Const_12, Const_13)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-17-dc904e64a78b>", line 1, in <module>
    col1.eval()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 465, in eval
    return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3097, in _eval_using_default_session
    return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 315, in run
    return self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 511, in _run
    feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 564, in _do_run
    target_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 586, in _do_call
    e.code)
InvalidArgumentError: Unquoted fields cannot have quotes/CRLFs inside
     [[Node: DecodeCSV_6 = DecodeCSV[OUT_TYPE=[DT_INT32, DT_INT32], field_delim=",", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](ReadFile, Const_12, Const_13)]]
Caused by op u'DecodeCSV_6', defined at:
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 488, in <module>
    pydevconsole.StartServer(pydev_localhost.get_localhost(), int(port), int(client_port))
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 334, in StartServer
    process_exec_queue(interpreter)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 209, in process_exec_queue
    more = interpreter.addExec(code_fragment)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 201, in addExec
    more = self.doAddExec(code_fragment)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console.py", line 42, in doAddExec
    res = bool(self.interpreter.addExec(codeFragment.text))
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 435, in addExec
    self.ipython.run_cell(line, store_history=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2902, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3006, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-0556330e1530>", line 3, in <module>
    tf.constant([],dtype=tf.int32)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_parsing_ops.py", line 38, in decode_csv
    field_delim=field_delim, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 655, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2040, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1087, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

How can I decode this csv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`tf.read_file()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#read_file) op reads the *entire* contents of the given file into a single string, whereas [`tf.decode_csv()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_csv) op expects each element of its input to be a single *record* (i.e. one line). Therefore you need something that reads one line at a time, which the [`tf.TextLineReader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#TextLineReader) supports.

Using a reader is slightly more complicated than using a simple op, because it's designed for reading large multi-file datasets with a lot of flexibility in how the files are chosen. You can see the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#reading-from-files) 
for a complete explanation, but the following example code should help to get you started:

```
# Read the file once.
filenames = tf.train.string_input_producer(["blah.txt"], num_epochs=1)

reader = tf.TextLineReader()

_, line = reader.read(filenames)

col1, col2 = tf.decode_csv(line,
                           record_defaults=[tf.constant([],dtype=tf.int32),
                                            tf.constant([],dtype=tf.int32)])
```

Now `col1` and `col2` represent single values. If you evaluate them, you'll get the contents of the next line:

```
# N.B. These must be called before evaluating the inputs.
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

print sess.run([col1, col2])  # ==> 1, 2
print sess.run([col1, col2])  # ==> 3, 4
```

If instead you want to batch the columns, you can use [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch):

```
_, line = reader.read(filenames)

# N.B. Batch size is 2, to match the size of your file.
line_batch, = tf.train.batch([line], batch_size=2)

col1, col2 = tf.decode_csv(line_batch,
                           record_defaults=[tf.constant([],dtype=tf.int32),
                                            tf.constant([],dtype=tf.int32)])

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

print sess.run([col1, col2])  # ==> [1, 3], [2, 4]
```

Comment: Just want to note here that to get this code working I had to remove `num_epochs`. Otherwise I get error `ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Attempting to use uninitialized value input_producer/limit_epochs/epochs`

Comment: That's a good point - I hadn't realized that `tf.string_input_producer()` uses a variable internally, so you need to run `tf.initialize_all_variables()` as well. (Most real programs use this at some point, so it's not always obvious when it's needed....) I updated my answer with the additional initialization step.

Comment: Im trying to figure out if it makes sense for me to use the tensorflow reader/queueing system if I only have 1 very large file (100,000 rows. 1 for each training example). Rows in the file can be processed in parallel. But it seems the queueing system is designed for cases where there are many files that need to be processed?

Comment: It's definitely designed to support the multi-file case (because the datasets we use are often sharded into multiple files, as the result of a MapReduce, etc.). As a result, the reader classes are a bit complicated, but I think they still work for a single-file use case. If you want to process the lines in parallel, your best bet is to enqueue those lines into *another* queue, and then have multiple training threads that dequeue from it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes thank you @mrry. In terms of this *other* queue... is that the 'example queue' described in the [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#creating-threads-to-prefetch-using-queuerunner-objects)?

Comment: That's correct. In the case of the tutorial, the "example queue" is implicitly created by [`tf.train.shuffle_batch_join()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch_join), which is one of a few [utility functions for this kind of batching](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batching-at-the-end-of-an-input-pipeline).

Comment: In this case is 'filename_queue' still necessary since there's only 1 file? It seems `TextLineReader` requires a queue so it seems like I need 'filename_queue' just for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately: all of the readers take a queue of filenames, rather than a constant. This is used for multi-file support, but also to determine how many times to read a particular file (based on the `num_epochs` argument). (We could make a convenience wrapper that just takes a string constant, but then it would be unclear whether to make it loop forever, or just once. We'll probably defer that decision to higher-level libraries for input handling.)

Comment: In the example, I believe `shuffle_batch_join()` is used to process multiple files in parallel. For the single file case, can it be processed in parallel by just using `tf.batch(...., num_threads=8)`? Or should I manually create a `tf.FIFOQueue` to hold the lines of the file?

Comment: Apologies for all the questions in the comments. Going to move this topic to a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689547/how-to-process-single-training-file-in-parallel